# Are the adjectives "utopic" and "dystopic" correct English words?

Tags: adjectives, suffixes

My dictionary only mentions the form ending in "ian" for both adjectives (utopian/dystopian) yet I do come across the "ic" ending in some decent writings. Would that be considered incorrect usage?

Comment: I'd certainly start by assuming anyone who came out with the *-ic* forms didn't have much of an ear for established usage. Undeniably there are valid contexts - such as a [dystopic kidney](http://www.almaany.com/home.php?language=english&lang_name=Arabic&word=dystopic+kidney++%3D++ectopic+kidney&category=Medical) *(= ectopic kidney, not in its normal position)*. But I think correct/incorrect isn't really the issue here - it's more a matter of *what do people normally say?*

Comment: Asked and answered, the endings in -ic are incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary has three citations, all from the twentieth century, illustrating *utopic*, of which the definition is given as ‘That embodies or proposes utopian ideals.’ There is no entry for ‘dystopic’. If you wish to use either word, it would be wise to do so, as always, only if it will achieve what you want it to achieve, taking into account the nature of your likely readers or listeners.